# jquery and stop()

Tags: jquery, opacity

Hello I still don't get how stop() works. It stops all current animations on the object right? How can I reset all the status too and do the next animation? It happens that if you have a fade in/fade out on mouse over/out if you do it fast it happens that the animation stops at half the fade Out and the next time the object won't even show anymore

```
        //show delete link on hover
    $('li.dir').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
          if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this ).find("span.delete_file").delay(800).fadeIn('fast');
          }
           else{
            $(this).find("span.delete_file").fadeOut('fast');
          }
    });
```

HTML

```
<li class="dir" title="">
                    <span class="pin"></span>
                    <span  class="name">test</span> 
                    <span class="delete_file" title="/test"></span>
                        <ul class="sub_folder">
                        </ul>

                </li>
```

How and where should I put stop() so that when I go over the li.dir the .delete_file fades In but in the same time the mouse out stops everything! It tried to play with stop() show() hide() but it always happens that if I move the mouse over and out very fast the animation "fadeIN" restarts from the last setting, which can be anything from 100%  to 0% opacity (not showing at all)

Answer (score 0):

You need to say:

```
$(this)....stop(true, true).fadeTo(1).fadeOut("fast");
```

and

```
$(this)....stop(true, true).fadeTo(0).fadeIn("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

[**This demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4QgN/1/) should do what you want. I changed the selector to create a more traditional [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)  combination. If you need the `delay()`   it can be added back. The demo is working with and without it for me.

[`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) tends to be called before calling an animation effect, thereby stopping a running animation before starting another.